# in slim how can I pass a file path into a variable?

Tags: php, get, urlencode, filepath, slim

what i have right now is:

```
$app->get(/folderBrowse/:path function($app){
bla bla bla 

}); // I know this is not using '' or , 
but it's just for example, because I've tried it with many configurations. my 
syntax is correct in my code, because it works fine when I don't pass a path
```

but when ever I pass in a file path even using URL encode it gives me a 404 page. is there something I'm missing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have the correct syntax post it here, what's the purpose of asking for help with wrong syntax?

Comment: my point was not to say I have wrong syntax... I was trying to say that I'm not trying to be specific about my syntax... I know it works. thanks for the response though. I'm trying to figure out how I can pass a file path through the URL with slim... it always gives me a 404 error when I do... even when I use the url encode method. is there some setting in slim that I need to change or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you can send stuff like file paths through the url like this

```
http://localhost/api/something?file_path=some url encoded string

$app->get('/something', function() use($app) {
  $file_path = $app->request()->get('file_path');
call some other stuff... etc

});
```